# error when change unix time into date-time via excel

Tags: excel, datetime, unix-timestamp, data-conversion

i want to convert a timestamp column into time. Imagine that this column is extended in 30000 rows

so when i put this formula =ROUND(DATEVALUE("1/1/1970")+A1/(60*60*24),0)

i get this:

## VALUE!

Why does this happen

I am using Microsoft office professional plus 2016

the time zone is UTC +2:00

Can you help me with the formula here?

Comment: What is the exact value in A1?  is it `UTC +2:00`?

Comment: The formula works with unix date/time so there must be something with the data in A1 that is causing the issue.

Comment: is depicted like this 1.59E+12

Comment: is  a timestamp from an accelerometer sensor 1585740000000 if i format the above shell

Comment: You have miliseconds in that number change the formula to: `ROUND(DATEVALUE("1/1/1970")+A1/(60*60*24*1000),0)`

Comment: thank you for your answer. i get the same error. I am using this formula in cell C2. 

A1, B1, C1 have the label of the dataframe

Comment: So i change the A1 TO C2 and i get back:

there are one or more circular elements where a formula refers to its own cell directly or inderectly. This may cause them to calculate incorrectly

Comment: If I put `1585740000000` in A1 and use the formula I gave you, it returns today's date.

Comment: You cannot use a formula on itself.

Comment: Thank you @scott craner

Comment: this formula works for A1 but how to adjust automatically  my other observation which goes down to 30000 rows? @ScottCraner

Comment: you will drag the formula down.